# Change systemd stop job timeout in NixOS configuration

Tags: systemd, nixos

The systemd stop job timeout defaults to 90s. Does NixOS have a configuration parameter to change this value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your `configuration.nix`:

```
systemd.extraConfig = ''
  DefaultTimeoutStopSec=10s
'';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about NixOS specifically, but `man systemd-system.conf` for me lists `DefaultTimeoutStopSec=` as *the default timeout for ... stopping of units*. A local administrator would typically change this in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`. A Unit can have its own `TimeoutStopSec=` value.